# regex to find a specific pattern in python

Tags: python, regex

I am using Python 2.7 and I have a great chunk of string data. I need to parse out a specific pattern from it. The pattern is as follows:

```
November 5 - December 10
Another example:
September 23 - December 16
```

I want to use a regex to find data in this pattern. That is a string of characters, followed by a space, followed by a number, followed by a ' - ' , and then a string of characters again and then space followed by a number!

I know it sounds complicated but can someone please help me!

Comment: how your output should look like?

Comment: Could you not split by space and grab the elements of the resulting list?

Comment: It should look like a list of all the strings in a list with the same pattern.

No splitting by spaces doesnt work

Comment: @HamzaTahir Oh okay, I thought you were having them like you posted them! ^^;

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just do this in a pretty straightforward way:

```
import re

text = """
November 5 - December 10
September 23 - December 16
"""

matches = re.findall("\w+\s\d+\s\-\s\w+\s\d+", text)
print matches
```

prints:

```
['November 5 - December 10', 'September 23 - December 16']
```

But, if these words are just month names, you can improve your regexp by specifying a list of months instead of just `\w+`:

```
months = "|".join(calendar.month_name)[1:]
matches = re.findall("{0}\s\d+\s\-\s{0}\s\d+".format(months), text)
```

Comment: `[^\W_]` instead of `\w` to exclude the underscore.

Comment: There is no underscore, theres just a dash

Comment: +1 for cool solution that dynamically builds regex in a very compact way... I've noticed your nice regex style, cruising through some old answers and seeing that for me it's a big education in Python. :)